# UI кнопка в Unity теряет свою фотографию при повторном нажатии

Tags: c#, unity3d, button

господа! Прописал отдельный скрипт для кнопок в unity. При нажатии всё работает, изображение меняется. Когда кнопку отпускаю обратно, то изображение тоже меняется обратно. Но после повторного отпускания кнопки, она теряет фотографию. [image] [image]

```
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class Button : MonoBehaviour
    {
public GameObject choosePerson;
public Sprite button, pressed;
private Image img;
private float yPos;
private Transform child;

public void Start()
{
    img = GetComponent <Image>();

    child = transform.GetChild(0).transform;
}

public void OnMouseDown()
{
    img.sprite = pressed;
    yPos = child.localPosition.y;
    child.localPosition = new Vector3(child.localPosition.x, 0, child.localPosition.z);
}

public void OnMouseUp()
{
    img.sprite = button;
    child.localPosition = new Vector3(child.localPosition.x, yPos, child.localPosition.z);
}

// тут прописаны смена сцен, на вид кнопки никак не влияет

IEnumerator loadScene(string scene)
{
    float fadeTime = Camera.main.GetComponent<Fading>().BeginFade(1);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена! В данном коде всё написано правильно. По структуре моей программы нужно было создать ещё один скрипт, частично такой же, как и этот. При написании программы зачем-то написал такую вещь:`Choose choose = gameObject.AddComponent<Choose>() as Choose;`. При нажатии на кнопку, ей добавлялся скрипт Choose и сбивал картинку с кнопки.